# How to relocate copied svn folder

Tags: svn, switch-statement

i copied an existing svn folder (a) to a new folder b and want to also switch the repository url. Its still pointing to a repo.

i try svn switch --relocate but only get:

svn: Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL

What is the right way to do this task?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have (a) point to repo (1) and now you have (b) pointing to repo (1) but you want (b) pointing to repo (2) ? Is that about right?

Comment: `svn switch --relocate` seems to be the right command for what you're trying to do. Double check the syntax and see if you're giving it the right parameters: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html

Comment: yes.

i already created an empty folder at repo 2. Now i need to point b to repo 2 and ci the content?

Comment: my syntax is like:

svn --relocate http://svnserver.com/some/folder/a http://svnserver.com/some/folder/b

Comment: If your repo2 is a _new_ repository, why do you want your existing checked out folders (b, which is a copy of a) pointing to it? Wouldn't a fresh checkout work?

Comment: See my answer. It doesn't work because you are changing folder path from a to b. relocate only changes the base repo URL

Comment: hm... pherhaps i did something wrong.. i copy a to b because i rename the hole project and changed some more things.

all i want to do is to checkin these changes to a new folder in the svn server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--relocate` can only change the base repository, not the path within a repository

For example:

To switch from `http://serverA/repo/path/to/dir` to another repo `http://serverB/repo/path/to/dir` you would type in:

`svn switch http://serverA/repo http://serverB/repo`

Read [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.switch) from the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

As per your comment

> my syntax is like: svn --relocate
>   svnserver.com/some/folder/a
>   svnserver.com/some/folder/b

You **cannot** use `--relocate` to change folder path, only the repo.

Comment: svn switch returns:

svn: 'https://svnserver/some/folder' is not a working copy
svn: 'https://svnserver/some/folder' does not exist

Comment: ok, my fault.. svn switch returns (correct syntax now)

svn: Directory 'somefolder' is missing

Thats right because the folder is empty and i first have to checkin.

Comment: no not really.. svn switch returns:

svn: Directory 'somefolder' is missing

What properly is right, cause the folder is still empty on the svn server.. i have to checkin my changes.

Comment: ok, finally fixed the problem with a clean import to the new folder. Thanks for your help!